# extracting date from from string

Tags: date, excel-formula

I have following string:

```
CO_CAS_REA_NO_VIPPLUS_20190402_BONUS
```

I would like to Extract the Date part (20190402) and convert it into DD/MM/YY format if possible.

I have tried some 'Search' and 'extraction' formulas but to no avail.

does anyone have any ideas how to do this in excel or VBA?

Other variations of the data string would be like:

```
COCASREAHVPLUSVIPUK20190827CRMFSDEP
COCASREALVWINFIDEGL20190809CRMPTS
COSBINFLVFIDE20190830CRMBET
CO_CAS_RET_HVMV_UK_20190830_RB
COSB_REA_181INF_HVMV_FIDE_20190809_CRM_RB
COSBREAHVMVGL20190831CRMFBFSQUAL
COSBINFLVNO20190816CRMFB
```

Comment: Can you share a few sample data (just to show the potential variations of the strings if they are not the same structure and same length) with the expected outcome?

Comment: other variations would be like  COCASREAHVPLUSVIPUK20190827CRMFSDEP
COCASREALVWINFIDEGL20190809CRMPTS
COSBINFLVFIDE20190830CRMBET
COSBINFLVNO20190816CRMFB
COSBREAHVMVGL20190831CRMFBFSQUAL
CO_CAS_RET_HVMV_UK_20190830_RB
COSB_REA_181INF_HVMV_FIDE_20190809_CRM_RB

Comment: Giving the further examples at the beginning would have meant some of us not wasting our time...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assume your data put in Column A

In B2, enter formula :

```
=0+TEXT(AGGREGATE(14,6,--MID(A1,ROW($1:$250),8),1),"0000-00-00")
```

Then, B2 >> Format Cell, in the Number tab, choose: "Date" >> select dd/mm/yy

All copied down

Answer (score 1):

Suppose in each string you only have **one 8-digit numerical string** representing the date in the form of `YYYYMMDD` that you want to extract, you can use one of the following three formulas to return the date:

[image: Example]

**Method 1:**

```
=DATE(LEFT(MAX(IFERROR(--MID(A1,ROW($A$1:INDEX($A:$A,LEN(A1))),8),0)),4),MID(MAX(IFERROR(--MID(A1,ROW($A$1:INDEX($A:$A,LEN(A1))),8),0)),5,2),RIGHT(MAX(IFERROR(--MID(A1,ROW($A$1:INDEX($A:$A,LEN(A1))),8),0)),2))
```

**Method 2:**

```
=DATEVALUE(LEFT(MAX(IFERROR(--MID(A1,ROW($A$1:INDEX($A:$A,LEN(A1))),8),0)),4)&"/"&MID(MAX(IFERROR(--MID(A1,ROW($A$1:INDEX($A:$A,LEN(A1))),8),0)),5,2)&"/"&RIGHT(MAX(IFERROR(--MID(A1,ROW($A$1:INDEX($A:$A,LEN(A1))),8),0)),2))
```

**Method 3:**

```
=DATEVALUE(TEXT(MAX(IFERROR(--MID(A1,ROW($A$1:INDEX($A:$A,LEN(A1))),8),0)),"0000-00-00"))
```

Please note, all methods are using **array formula** so you **MUST** press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> upon finishing the formula in the formula bar otherwise they will not function correctly. Then you can simply drag the formula down to apply across.

> The logic is to use this array formula `=MAX(IFERROR(--MID(A1,ROW($A$1:INDEX($A:$A,LEN(A1))),8),0))` to extract the numerical string first. Method 1 & 2 follow the same logic which is to extract the `year YYYY`, `month MM` and `day DD` component from the numerical string and then use use **DATE** or **DATEVALUE** function to return the date. Method 3 is using a formatting trick to quickly turn the numerical value into a text date and then use **DATEVALUE** function to convert the text date into a "real" date.

Let me know if you have any questions. Cheers :)

Answer (score 0):

with excel-formula, make use of `MID()` function

```
=MID("CO_CAS_REA_NO_VIPPLUS_20190402_BONUS",23, 8)
```

with VBA, you can split it with "_"

```
dte_str = Split("CO_CAS_REA_NO_VIPPLUS_20190402_BONUS", "_")(5)
```

Answer (score 0):

You might find this more flexible if the text to the left changes:

[image]

Just to save you typing here is the formula in cell C1:

```
=MID(A1,FIND("LUS_",A1,1)+4,FIND("_BON",A1,1)-FIND("LUS_",A1,1)-4)
```

It does however assume that the 4 characters either side of the date are always the same.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the strings are in Column A and you're only looking for the year 2019 you could use this

```
=DATE(LEFT(MID(A1,SEARCH(2019,A1),8),4), MID(MID(A1,SEARCH(2019,A1),8),5,2), RIGHT(MID(A1,SEARCH(2019,A1),8),2))
```